# Android multi video player simultaneously

Tags: android, video, media-player, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer

I am striving to create a simple Android media player that can play multiple videos simultaneously on a single screen. So basically a single media player screen is divided into multiple parts, and each part plays a given video. Is it feasible to do it within current Android API? Or is there any existing Android sample/library or anything that can do that? If we need to use multiple media players glued together, we should make sure there is no bordering or edges as if it is whole a single media player. Of course a limited number of videos are expected to play.

A neat and ideal call of such player can be similar to Android's default `mediaplayer` and extends it given multiple media inputs, such as

```
MultiMediaPlayer mmp = new MultiMediaPlayer ();
mmp.add(video1,0,0,50,50);
mmp.add(video2, 51, 51, 100, 100);
...
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, I am afraid there is no support natively from Android. But you have to instantiate multi players and take care of display window management.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. But can you help to come up with a working example?

Comment: @TinaJasmin, in Android SDK are you able to load one video object & choose it's display size & position on the app canvas? Well do that for 3 more video objects. That's what is being suggested. Maybe show some code of what you've tried & someone will try help you to fix it?

Comment: @TinaJasmin, had done that a few years ago. I'll try to pull out that code. Conceptually, what I said and what VC.One elaborated is what would work for you.